# How to extend router wire?

Tags: wire, awg, router

I have a router with 2m wire, and it would be really useful to extending it a little. I was thinking about cut in somewhere and add 2 'nipple' (not sure if proper word) to connect them with new 3m wire. I checked current wire and there is some info:
2468 YIHUAXING 300V 1A 18AWG.
I have two questions:

1. Can I do that and will that be secure for device and people?
2. Since I cant buy this one, and dont see anything with 'AWG' in my local stores what should I care about? V and A I assume, anything more?

Comment: What if was an electric sander? How would you extend the reach from the outlet.

Comment: Is this a router as in the networking equipment, or a router as in the machining tool?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. I think you are asking about extending the DC cable from the mains power supply (probably a "wall wart" power supply) to the router.DC input jack.

Your router will require less than 1 amp at about 12 V. Any 2-core cable of similar size will work. You need to make sure that you keep the polarity the same.

AWG is American Wire Guage. You will find metric converters online.